# Exp:resso Store: Communication

Tags: expresso-store

Exp:resso Store: How can I communicate to a list of all members who have purchased a particular product?

If, for example, a product (in our case, a class course) is cancelled or the time changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a query that queries the `exp_store_order_items` joined with the `exp_store_orders` table to grab the members email that `order_id` matches the `entry_id` in question.